# Fragment Replacement

Tags: android, android-activity, replacewith

Is there any way to replace the main layout in the navigation drawer with the Activity which **extends AppCombatActivity not the Fragment**.

Because whenever I do so it gives me the error that :
**Wrong 2nd argument type. Found:'myapp.hp.com.drawerdemo1.Main2Activity', required:'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment)in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to(int,myapp.hp.com.drawerdemo1.Main2Activity)**

I was doing this :

```
    if (id == R.id.nav_start) {
        // Handle the camera action
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);
        Main2Activity main = new Main2Activity();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment_Layout, main);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Point to be noted :
**I don't need intent activity as it opens up the activity in  the other layout which doesn't look much interactive.**

What is the reason I want the activity layout instead of fragment layout :

- In the class which extends Fragment its hard to perform and handle different action like button click and so on.
- Difficult to initialize different events.
- Main reason is that I'm naive at handling Fragments.

Please help as I need it. I'll appreciate if you will look forward to this problem and give me a solution.
Thank You..:)

Answer (score 0):

In a fragment transaction you have to provide a fragment, that's just kind of self-evident.

> In the class which extends Fragment its hard to perform and handle different action like button click and so on.

How so? Handling click events in a fragment and activity are done exactly the same way

> Difficult to initialize different events.

How so?

> Main reason is that I'm naive at handling Fragments.

Would recommend learning about them as it is impossible to progress much in Android development without being well-versed in fragments and how they are used.